# How to fix Yarn packages are out of date in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yarnpkg

I am always after being installed yarn.

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.0.rc2 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Usage: yarn [options]

yarn: error: no such option: --integrity


========================================
  Your Yarn packages are out of date!
  Please run `yarn install --check-files` to update.
========================================


To disable this check, please change `check_yarn_integrity`
to `false` in your webpacker config file (config/webpacker.yml).
```

Comment: related: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1135

Answer (score 14):

Try:

- Updating node and yarn
- Deleting `node_modules` directory and running `yarn install` again

Answer (score 6):

Check your yarn version using `yarn --version`. If the version is less than 1.21.1
Update using `curl --compressed -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash`.
The run 
`yarn install` on projects root

Answer (score 0):

Like it suggested did you put in `yarn install --check-files` that should update any out of date packages. You can also do `yarn upgrade` to update. Unless you are certain you don't want to upgrade in which case when you install a package put in the specific version.